Docker Compose Setup: Publisher fails to conenct to RabbitMQ
I'm working on a project that used Docker Compose to orchestrate a multi-container setup involving, RabbitMQ, PostgreSQL, and two .NET services: a publisher and a subscriber. The goal is to have a system where the publisher sends messages to a RabbitMQ queue, and the subscriber consumes those messages and stores them in a PostgreSQL database.
Components

RabbitMQ:


Purpose: Acts as a message broker that handles communication between the publisher and subscriber.
Configuration: Running on the default ports 5672(AMQP) and 15672 (management interface)


PostgreSQL:


purpose: Stores the message received by the subscriber
configuration: Exposed on the port 5432 with a database named messages_db-

3.Publisher Service:

Purpose: Publishes messages to the RabbitMQ queue.
Configuration: Built from a .NET project. The Dockerfile includes steps to build and publish the  application, and the container should attempt to connect to RabbitMQ and send messages.

4.Subscriber Service:

Purpose: Consumes messages from the RabbitMQ queue and writes them to the PostgreSQL database.
Configuration: Also built from a .NET project. The container connects to both RabbitMQ and PostgreSQL.

What’s Supposed to Happen:

The publisher connects to RabbitMQ and sends messages to a queue.
The subscriber listens to the queue, receives messages, and stores them in the PostgreSQL database.

Problem
The publisher service fails to connect to RabbitMQ with the error None of the specified endpoints were reachable. Despite the RabbitMQ service and other components being up and running, the publisher service is unable to communicate with RabbitMQ.
Details
docker-compose.yaml config
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - app-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmq-diagnostics", "-q", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: messages_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - app-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U user -d messages_db"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  publisher:
    build:
      context: ./Publisher
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
    command: ["dotnet", "run"]
    networks:
      - app-network

  subscriber:
    build:
      context: ./Subscriber
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=messages_db
      - DB_USER=user
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
    command: ["dotnet", "run"]
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

Dockerfile
# Stage 1: Build stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Publisher.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "Publisher.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "Publisher.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# Stage 2: Publish stage
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Publisher.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Stage 3: Runtime stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping net-tools
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "ping -c 4 rabbitmq && netstat -tuln && dotnet Publisher.dll"]

What could be causing the None of the specified endpoints were reachable error in the publisher service? How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Checked if the RabbitMQ service is up and running by accessing the RabbitMQ management interface.

Verified network configuration in Docker Compose.

Confirmed that the RabbitMQ hostname rabbitmq is resolvable from within the publisher container.



The error went away the code runs the way it should when i changed the connection factory in publisher.cs to:
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
{
    HostName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RABBITMQ_HOST") ?? "rabbitmq"
};

I am not really sure why.
